# Python: IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 7

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm trying to loop over a matrix and replacing the entries using operations involving the matrices around it:

For example,

```
 xarray = np.array([3,35,7,9,8,7,6])
 yarray = np.array([2,5,1,7,3,59,2])
 zarray = np.array([3,5,6,3.5,69,2,1])
 barray = np.array([1,5,56,7,24,2,1])
 carray = np.array([1,5,56,7,24,2,1])
 darray = np.array([1,5,56,7,24,2,1])
 earray = np.array([1,5,56,7,24,2,1])
 Q = np.array([xarray,yarray,zarray,barray,carray,darray,earray])
k = np.shape(Q)
for i in range(k[0]):
    for j in range(k[1]):
```

`$`taking into account entries on the corners which don't have the same amount of surrounding matrices

```
        if i==0 or j==0 or i == k[0] or j == k[1]:
            Q[i,j] = Q[i,j]
        else:
            Q[i,j] = (Q[i,j]+Q[i-1,j]+Q[i+1,j]+Q[i,j+1]+Q[i-1,j-1]+Q[i-1,j+1])*3
print Q
```

But I get the error above. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Q` has shape `(7,7)`.That means it can be indexed from 0 to 6. However in the loop where `i` is already 6, `Q[i+1,j]` will fail.

Comment: I thought my if statement prevented this; would you mind helping further?

Comment: Ah - just realised my mistake - indexing error, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in python indexes start from 0, which means if `i` or `j` is equal to the length of the array, you'll get an error

All I've done here is switched `range(k[x])` for `range(k[x] - 1)`

```
for i in range(k[0] - 1):
    for j in range(k[1] - 1):
        if i==0 or j==0:
            Q[i,j] = Q[i,j]
        else:
            Q[i,j] = (Q[i,j]+Q[i-1,j]+Q[i+1,j]+Q[i,j+1]+Q[i-1,j-1]+Q[i-1,j+1])*3
```